# Does both the language and its complement being context free imply it being deterministic context-free?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar, pushdown-automata

Suppose $L \subset A^*$ is context free and $A^*\setminus L$ is also context free. Does it mean, that $L$ is deterministic context free?

If it is not, I would like to see a counterexample (I failed to construct one myself).

Note that the converse is true. Moreover, a complement to a deterministic context free language is also deterministic context free as one can simply change labels on the corresponding deterministic pushdown automaton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as shown in this [answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/4264) and [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/37966) on cs.stackexchange.
You cannot even conclude that your language is unambiguous, as shown in this [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/98850).